# Global styles not working in Storybook (v6.5) with Next.js v13.1.6

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, storybook

I am facing an issue with global styles in Storybook(v6.5) not working on Next.js version 13.1.6. I have set up the same configuration on ReactJS and it's working perfectly fine. In my Next.js project, I have a preview.js file where I import my global styles from '../src/styles/globals.css' and set up the parameters for actions and controls. However, the global styles are not applied in Storybook. Can someone please help me with this issue?

NextJS:

```
import '../src/styles/globals.css'
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

ReactJS:

```
import '../src/index.css'
export const parameters = {
  actions: { argTypesRegex: "^on[A-Z].*" },
  controls: {
    matchers: {
      color: /(background|color)$/i,
      date: /Date$/,
    },
  },
}
```

Global CSS:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@layer base {
  /* Write your own custom base styles here */

  :root {
    /* main theme color  */
    --tw-color-primary-200: 158 178 208; /* #9EB2D0 
...........
```

Tailwindconfig.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    container: {
      center: true,
      padding: {
        DEFAULT: '2rem',
        sm: '2rem',
        lg: '2rem',
        xl: '2rem',
        '2xl': '2rem',
      },
    },
    .....
}
```